# How to move items/buttons from one div to another using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs on html page. Which are basically nothing but two columns on html layout. I have a list of buttons in left column (div). I have marked each button with OK and REMOVE glyphicons. Now I want that when I click REMOVE icon of the button then it should remove it otherwise if I click OK icon of button then it should move it to the right column (div). I have created a js fiddle here: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amitJS/kz2bsfgf/7/)

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;border: solid 1px blue;">
            <div class="text-center">
          <div class="list">
          </div>
</div>      
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;border: solid 1px blue;">
            <div class="accepted">
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var load = function () {
    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4skih', function (res) {
    $.each(res.data, function (key, val) {
        addTag(val.tag, key);
    });
  });
};

var init = function () {
    load();
    $('.list').on('click', 'button', function () {
        $(this).parent().acceptTag(this);
                $(this).parent().remove();
    });
};

$(document).ready(init);

// Add tag to html.
var addTag = function (tag) {
    $("<div><button class='tag'>" + tag + "</button><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true''></span><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true''></span></div>").appendTo('.list');
};
var acceptTag = function (tag) {
    $("<div><button class='tag'>" + tag + "</button><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true''></span><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true''></span></div>").appendTo('.accepted');
};
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really made slight change to your code to make it work.
You were close!

**Explanation**:
Your call to the `acceptTag` function was incorrect, in the `.list` event delegation on `button` click.
I called it simply as you've had done with the `addTag` function in the `load()` function.

And I simplifed this `acceptTag` function since, obviously, you wanted to send the parent object ( the wrapping `div`) to it.

So all the `button` definition was already existing. It is retrieved by `tag.html()`, which is the button's parent HTML content. You just have to re-wrap it again in a `div`.

See my **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/tsh5gm02/)**

```
var load = function () {
    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4skih', function (res) {
    $.each(res.data, function (key, val) {
        addTag(val.tag, key);
    });
  });
};

var init = function () {
    load();
    $('.list').on('click', 'button', function () {
        acceptTag( $(this).parent() );              // Changes here
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
};

$(document).ready(init);

// Add tag to html.
var addTag = function (tag) {
    $("<div><button class='tag'>" + tag + "</button><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true''></span><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' aria-hidden='true''></span></div>").appendTo('.list');
};
var acceptTag = function (tag) {                // Changes here
    $('.accepted').append( "<div>" +tag.html()+ "</div>" );
};
```

Comment: Instead of expecting people to find the change a quick explanation helps

Comment: Ok @charlietfl, I will try an explanation.

Comment: @charlietfl: Do you think these explanations are clear enought? ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @Louys Patrice Bessette. Now its working.